# Storing and retrieving zip files in SQLite gives "Could not decode to UTF-8"

Tags: python, sqlite, unicode-string

I have a table in SQLite 3 as follows and I am planning on using it to store a variety of files: txt, pdf, images and zip files.

```sql
CREATE TABLE zip (filename TEXT PRIMARYKEY NOT NULL, zipfile BLOB NOT NULL);
```

To store and retrieve I am experimenting with the following python code

```py
#!env/bin/python


import sqlite3 as lite
import os
import sys

def insertfile(_filename):
    try:
        con = lite.connect('histogram.db', detect_types=lite.PARSE_DECLTYPES)
        con.row_factory = lite.Row
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute('PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;')
        _f = open(_filename,'rb')
        _split = os.path.split(_filename)
        _file = _split[1]
        _blob = _f.read()
        cur.execute('INSERT INTO zip (filename,zipfile) VALUES (?,?)', (_file,lite.Binary(_blob)))
        _f.close()
        con.commit()
        cur.close()
        con.close()
    except Exception as ex:
        print ex

def getfile(_filename):
    try:
        con = lite.connect('histogram.db', detect_types=lite.PARSE_DECLTYPES)
        con.row_factory = lite.Row
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute('PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;')
        cur.execute('SELECT zipfile from zip where filename = ?', (_filename,))
        _files = cur.fetchall()
        if len(_files) > 0:
            _file  = open('Test/'+ _filename,'wb')
            _file.write(_files[0]['zipfile'])
            _file.close()
        cur.close()
        con.close()
    except Exception as ex:
        print ex

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print 'works'
    insertfile(sys.argv[1])
    getfile(os.path.split(sys.argv[1])[1])
```

When I test this on files like `.txt`, `.py`, `.pdf` etc., it works fine.

With Zip files, there is no error while storing into the table but an error while retrieving the file:

> Could not decode to UTF-8 column 'zipfile' with text 'PK '

There seems to be some encoding or decoding issue.

Comment: These filetypes aren't natively supported on python. If you try opening those filetypes in a notepad you will see that they are random blurbs

Comment: Thanks - but I am just trying to store the bytes of the file - open with 'rb' and 'wb' options to store files as binary data. I have been able to address the issue for pdfs, pngs etc by storing the file using lite.Binary(_blob). The zip files are still giving me issues while retreival

Comment: Could you please paste the full trace?

Comment: @Daniel The code is now working. Not sure how the zip file issue was corrected. Just to try out I commented out the insertion and just ran the retrieval and it worked. Now when I un-commented the insertion the program works fine. No Idea why the zip files were giving an error before.

Comment: Could it be that `detect_types=lite.PARSE_DECLTYPES` tries to convert your byte-blob into a UTF-8 string, but fails, because it's not a valid UTF-8 string? I would remove that and try again.

Comment: Glad to hear. Please write that up as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I basically tried using the code from one of the questions

[Insert binary file in SQLite database with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310584/insert-binary-file-in-sqlite-database-with-python)
.

It worked originally for the pdf, png, jpg files. But I was still getting the error for Zip files. When I commented out the insertion and just ran the retrieval code it worked. Now the code below works.

```
def insertfile(_filename):
    try:
        con = lite.connect('histogram.db', detect_types=lite.PARSE_DECLTYPES)
        con.row_factory = lite.Row
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute('PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;')
        _f = open(_filename,'rb')
        _split = os.path.split(_filename)
        _file = _split[1]
        _blob = _f.read()
        cur.execute('INSERT INTO zip (filename,zipfile) VALUES (?,?)', (_file,lite.Binary(_blob)))
        _f.close()
        con.commit()
        cur.close()
        con.close()
    except Exception as ex:
        print ex

def getfile(_filename):
    try:
        con = lite.connect('histogram.db', detect_types=lite.PARSE_DECLTYPES)
        con.row_factory = lite.Row
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute('PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;')
        cur.execute('SELECT zipfile from zip where filename = ?', (_filename,))
        _files = cur.fetchall()
        if len(_files) > 0:
            _file  = open('Downloads/'+ _filename,'wb')
            _file.write(_files[0]['zipfile'])
            _file.close()
        cur.close()
        con.close()
    except Exception as ex:
        print ex

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print 'works'
    insertfile(sys.argv[1])
    getfile(os.path.split(sys.argv[1])[1])
```